# Как заключить вот этот код в img с квадратными скобками?

Tags: javascript, html5

Типа BB кода для картинки, точно так же нужно и для GIFки на форум. Просто через img и URL ссылку не получается. Точнее получается, но мне нужно, чтобы заставка (рамка) появилась на форуме, а не просто ссылка.
Вот встроенный код гифки, но его мало, нужно его связать с квадратными скобками, то есть оформить в BB стиле кода:  `<iframe src="https://gifer.com/embed/1RhL" width=480 height=480.000 frameBorder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe><p><a href="https://gifer.com">через GIFER</a></p>`

Comment: `<img src="https://i.gifer.com/1RhL.webp">` — нормально отображается. Не совсем понятно, что у вас есть, и что именно нужно) Заменить какой-нибудь `[GIF]адрес[/GIF]` на `<img src="адрес">` - дело простого регулярного выражения.

Comment: С кодами [gif][/gif] не работает

Comment: Нужно только с квадратными скобками код, иначе не заработает. Это BB код разметки.

Comment: И вообще GIF такого нет кода. Это вы придумали...

Comment: Вы поймите, тут **помогают разобраться с кодом**, а не пишут код - для этого вам на фриланс.